# A numeric comparison was attempted on "$(lastknowntypescriptversion) that evaluates to "" instead of a number

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, build, msbuild

I have a proejct in Visual Studio 2015 and I installed Typescript 1.8.11. My project is failing to build with the error "A numeric comparison was attempted on "$(lastknowntypescriptversion) that evaluates to "" instead of a number". How do I resolve this?

Comment: How did you set the value of `$(lastknowntypescriptversion)` in your project file? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20379359/msb4086-a-numeric-comparison-was-attempted

Comment: It's set automatically in the `Microsoft.TypeScript.Targets` file which is imported when you create a new project. -- Updating Visual Studio makes the project no longer open or build.  Awesome job guys.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like, at some point in the last few months one of the standard Visual Studio updates breaks existing web projects -- it causes them to not build with this error message, and in some cases, not even open because of the error message.

I've found that Installing the latest TypeScript SDK via `Tools` -> `Extensions and Updates` -> `Online` and then typing in `TypeScript` and downloading and installing that extension (and *then* restarting Visual Studio) has fixed the issue for me.

My guess is that they have transitioned from having `TypeScript` being built-in to requiring it to being installed as an add-on.  The latest version that I was able to find via that list was 3.4.1.

In your specific case, I recommend uninstalling whatever 1.8.* version you grabbed and grabbing the 3.4.1 version located at: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55258 (which can also be found via the process above, in case the link changes).

Comment: @BrainSlug83 Thank you, this worked for me. Loading a solution worked on by others, one project failed with the exception given. Opening that project's .csproj file in a text editor revealed a TypeScriptToolsVersion of 2.6. Searching online in Extensions and Updates and installing "TypeScript 2.9.2 for Visual Studio 2015" enabled that project to load and the solution to compile. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This error happened when opening a solution with an old web project trying **VS 2022 preview** (with .NET Web Development and C++ workloads)... From [Microsoft Docs Walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/walkthrough-using-msbuild):

> If you have Visual Studio, then you already have MSBuild installed. With Visual Studio 2019 and later, it's installed under the Visual Studio installation folder.
>
> To install MSBuild on a system that doesn't have Visual Studio, go to Visual Studio downloads and scroll down to All Downloads, then expand Tools for Visual Studio 2019. Install Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019, which includes MSBuild, or **install the .NET Core SDK**.

So from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download I installed the .Net Core v3.1 SDK (includes the runtime), since VS 2022 installed v5. However, even with restarts, nothing seemed to work. The solution I found was:

- **installing Visual Studio 2019** with the same workloads

Now even just opening the solution in VS 2022, the web project loads properly.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove this line in the project configuration file

```
<TypeScriptToolsVersion>3.5</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
```

Answer (score 0):

I uninstall VS2017 and install VS2022, maybe it modify some settings of `TypeScript Tool for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015`, and I go `Contorl Panel > Program and Features > find TypeScript Tool program > Repair`,

After repair success, restart VS2015 and I can open projet successfully.

Answer (score -1):

Please try to restart your visual studio, this will probably solve your problem.

Comment: Restarting VS solved the problem for me (Thank you! :D), but waiting for 30 mins is irrelevant.